# Minimum Absolute Difference in an Array

Tags: python, arrays

Hi I have Solved this Minimum Absolute Difference in an Array problem with this Solution:

```
min_diff = 99999999
difference = 0  

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for y in range(len(arr)):
        if i != y:
            defference = abs(arr[i] - arr[y])
            if defference < min_diff:
                min_diff = defference
                
return min_diff
```

so as you can see my solution is O(n2) and it is giving a Time limit exceeded error so I have copied another solution which is this :

```
arr = sorted(arr)

# Initialize difference as infinite
diff = 10**20

# Find the min diff by comparing adjacent
# pairs in sorted array
for i in range(n-1):
    if arr[i+1] - arr[i] < diff:
        diff = arr[i+1] - arr[i]

# Return min diff
return diff
```

so as you can see it is the same as my code with time complexity so why this good is working correctly I didn't get the Time limit exceeded error. Please tell me what is the difference between my code and the code I have copied.

Comment: Sorting is O(n*logn), and then you iterate the array once for O(n), ending up with O(n*logn) for the entire solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to think about `O(n)` estimates is to count how many nested loops you have. Your code has two loops, so it is "quadratic" and would require 100^2 = 10,000 cycles for 100 elements. Theirs has one loop ("linear") and requires about 100 cycles for 100 elements.

Comment: Thanks It means When I use nested loops it takes more time than two simple forloop?

Comment: @AkifObaidi: yes. If the outer loop loops A times and the inner one loops B times, the total number of loops will be A*B